# How to get fitted sheets on bed?

Tags: bedroom

I always have trouble with fitted sheets on bed. One corner always slips off while I'm trying to stretch another on. Any tips?

Comment: This is not at all a life hack, but Threshold brand sheets have an excellent corner design that includes elastic and bunched-up material. The fitted sheet corners hold well but are easy to put on. I believe the design is patent pending. They sell them at Target; I'm not sure if it's their store brand.

Comment: My spouse and I often team up for this particular task. If that's not an option, I like to put my hands under the two corners that go at the head of the bed, then lay face-down on the bed and slip both hands over... but it's not really efficient... :0

Comment: Ever since we started buying one size larger all those issues were gone. It makes me believe that manufacturers give us the maximum size of a mattress their sheets will just fit and that they do not include the mattress thickness.

Answer (score 5):

After some thorough browsing ...
(after years of following my own advice, I can confirm these tips are effective)

- Start with the hardest corner to reach and snuggly apply the fitted sheet there.

  - Note: The elastic should rest [under the mattress](http://ep.yimg.com/ay/comfort/twin-xl-deep-pocket-bottom-sheet-52.gif), not on the side
- Grab the corner diagonally across from the one you just applied and secure it in place
- Tuck in the other two corners

Tucking in diagonal corners first will help ensure the maximum stress between two points. This serves the purpose of more quickly "telling" you if you've insecurely fastened the first sheet, as well as providing a strong foundation for the process if you've done it correctly.

Related tip: Consider making a small mark on the corners of your fitted sheet to help instruct you which corner goes where!

Sources:
[Reddit 1](https://www.reddit.com/r/LifeProTips/comments/1dj9b6/lpt_when_changing_fitted_sheets_start_putting_the/)
[Reddit 2](https://www.reddit.com/r/LifeProTips/comments/40k16j/lpt_request_how_to_put_a_fitted_sheet_on_a_bed/)
[Meta Filter](http://ask.metafilter.com/202463/Easier-way-to-put-a-fitted-sheet-on-a-daybed#2917026)
[A & M](http://www.arshammirshah.com/the-best/way-to-put-on-bed-sheets)

Answer (score 2):

Place something sufficiently heavy at one corner and secure at the other end. Do not be hard in pulling the cover.Simple!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Sheet suspenders](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00451BG2G), or [sheet straps](https://www.walmart.com/ip/SHEET-STRAPS-Keep-Sheets-Tightly-on-Bed/40120522), or whatever you may call them.  Put one corner on, fasten the strap in place, it should help greatly in holding the sheet in position while you work the other corners.

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily hold the first corner in place using some kind of strong clip. I'm a fan of binder clips, and I imagine bulldog clips would work too.

[image]

Once the first corner is clipped in place, then you can secure the other corners more easily. If you find any of them are slipping, you can clip each one in place as you go.

When all four corners of the fitted sheet are in place, remove the clips.

Comment: Curious about the reason behind the downvote....

Comment: @same, tbh. seems like a perfectly "hacky" sort of answer that fits right in.