# How do I slip on the last corner of a fitted sheet?

Tags: bedroom

The last corner of the fitted sheet does not go smoothly, even with elastic holders. How do I get the last corner to fit?

Comment: Hi TAXLADYX, Welcome to Lifehacks.

Comment: related: [How to Get Fitted Sheets on Bed](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/11622/how-to-get-fitted-sheets-on-bed)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to put the bottom fitted sheet onto a mattress is after it has been mangled (ironed)—as opposed to hot out of the dryer.

Some don't want to go to the trouble of pressing their sheets.
I certainly don't.

I fit the top corners and then one bottom corner as you do. Leave the remaining corner inside out. Place your fist inside the corner as if it was a pocket. Use your fist to pull (and stretch) the sheet by this corner over the mattress corner and downward until the elastic edge is below the mattress. With your free hand to help, turn the corner to the correct position and tuck it in. Continue by working on the head, foot, and sides of the sheet to finish the fit. As you push your fist downward, you'll naturally run out of sheet as you approach the bottom. This is the desired effect. You'll also want to take care not to snag your nails. Good work, TAXLADYX.

This works due to the amount of force you can exert with your fist is much greater than the grip you can hold onto the sheet fabric with your fingers. The corner of the sheet fabric which is quite sturdy, helps disperse your effort to the rest of the sheet to stretch it evenly into a smooth tight fit.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Great question! It's incredible how difficult this still is in the 21st century!

My trick is to:

1) LIFT the mattress,

2) put my foot on the bed base, under the mattress

3) lower the mattress so it rests on my knee

This forms a bend in the mattress, shortening the distance between this corner and the other 3

4) use both hands to pull the corner over the mattress

5) as long as the sheet is sufficiently pulled under the mattress, it will stay in place as you lower the corner to its normal place.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this method to great success for the past few years.

Obviously, I'm assuming that you have the correct size fitted sheet for the [correct size bed](https://www.sleepadvisor.org/mattress-size-chart/).

## Start with opposite Corners

1. Hardest to reach corner
2. Opposite corner from step 1
3. The other two corners (doesn't matter which)

For all corners, make sure that the elastic is ***under*** the mattress, not on the side of it.

This should keep the fitted sheet snug and neat.

Answer (score 0):

Fitted sheets that have fabric dudes sewn into corners are generally more reliable than rectangles of fabric that have elastic hoops at each corner

If you tumble dry your sheet it may have shrunk and will be an ill fit. Dry your sheet less in the dryer and put it on the mattress while it is still damp. leave the duvet/blanket/cover off for a while to allow the sheet to dry naturally

If it is old and has been tumble dried a lot it may forever be a worse fit than a new one; replacement would be the option in this case, but try fitting damp or wet (spun but not dried) in the first instance

If your bed has a foot board, pulling the mattress onto it so it is slightly bent will shorten the distance a tight sheet has to fit over and make for an easier fit, but ensure  the corners are well fitted for when you push the mattress back otherwise they may just ping off again

Answer (score 0):

Secure the bottom two corners of the fitted sheet to the mattress - then, while holding the top 2 corners in opposite hands,  leap across the bed and secure the top two at the same time. Your body will be in a 'Y' shape position if you have done this correctly.

Comment: Is this for a king sized bed?

Comment: @Acccumulation I've never had a bed that big - but it should work in principal. I have a queen size and the above technique works well! I have about a 6' wingspan.

Comment: Hi David, Welcome to Lifehacks. Between linen changes, I could practice leaping tall buildings with a single bound.